# Lost my original keystore but I do have the original password

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore

I do have my password to generate the keystore. So I generate a new keystore with the same password and alias but the SHA1 is different than the one uploaded to playstore.

[image]

Is ther something I can do not have to delete my app and upload it again?

Comment: Are you enrolled in Play Signing or not? You can check that in the "App signing" page in the Play Console. If you're enrolled in Play Signing, then the answer below will work. If not, then you'll have to create a new app.

Answer (score 0):

Without Key store we cannot upload every key is different.

Follow this steps

1. Go to your play console
2. Go to App Signing
3. Click on reset your key or use this [Reset Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key)

Or

Use [Click to Chat for Reset keystore](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en)